# Is mapping space locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let X be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Let Y be a Hausdorff space.

Consider M =$Top$ (X,Y) with compact open topology.

> Is M locally compact?

Comment: It's worth noting that a necessary condition is that $Y$ is locally compact.

Comment: Even with also locally compact $Y$ it can fail quite badly. For $X=[0,1]$, $Y=\Bbb R$ the compact-open topology on $C(X,Y)$ is not locally compact (A linear space never is unless it's finite dimensional).

Comment: To complete HennoBrandsma's comment, since $\mathbb{R}\cong(0,1)$ is an open subspace of $[0,1]$, the space $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ embeds into $C([0,1],[0,1])$ as an open subspace. Thus $C([0,1],[0,1])$ is not locally compact, so not even restricting to compact Hausdorff spaces is sufficient to give a positive answer to the question.